# CSS class won't work

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am slightly new to html and css and want to create my own portfolio. I have some problems with the classes though. Whenever I try to call them in css it doesn't seem to do what its supposed to do.

When I call it without using classes it works perfectly fine.

Hope somebody can help and find my mistake, 
thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Xander Feliers - Portfolio</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Portfolio - Xander Feliers">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <nav>
            <ul class="header_nav">
                <li class="header_nav"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="header_nav"><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li class="header_nav"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="header_nav"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  background-color: #f1f6fe;
}

.header_nav{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:#78aefa;
  width: 250 px;
}

li.header_nav{
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

a.header_nav {
  font-family: arial;
  display: block;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14 px 16 px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Changed css but still doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Which style is not getting applied?

Comment: There are no `a.header_nav` elements.

Comment: can u provide us a working example in https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You should use the descendant selectors. Not combinators if you are trying that HTML. https://jsfiddle.net/pxhoj8w5/

Comment: Only the body style is applied, I know there is no a.header_nav element is this example. But I have tried it aswell

Comment: Several answers explain the "what" but none so far explain "why" ... See: https://css-tricks.com/whats-the-difference/ ... There's a difference between using `a.header_nav` (applies to an `<a>` that itself has the class "header_nav") and `.header_nav a` (applies to any `<a>` that's a child of a parent with class `header_nav`). Which one you use may differ based on what effect you actually intend for this to have.

Comment: Also, it's not clear specifically what the problem is you're asking about. Which class isn't working, and what's the desired effect? Adding more detail might help.

Comment: It is clear. `a.header_nav ` - doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class won't work.
You pointed to the link with class `header_nav`. But you don't have it.

```
a.header_nav {
  font-family: arial;
  display: block;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14 px 16 px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

It should be (link inside the class `.header_nav`)

```
.header_nav a {
  font-family: arial;
  display: block;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14 px 16 px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've included the snippet. Is it what you want?

```css
body{
  background-color: #f1f6fe;
}

.header_nav{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:#78aefa;
  width: 250 px;
}

li.header_nav{
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.header_nav a {
  font-family: arial;
  display: block;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14 px 16 px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Xander Feliers - Portfolio</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Portfolio - Xander Feliers">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <nav>
            <ul class="header_nav">
                <li class="header_nav"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="header_nav"><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li class="header_nav"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="header_nav"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 2**
Order in the CSS is really mater. If you want to enforce your style you can use `!important` after the style. (Although I saw the articles where it's considered as bad practice.)

```
.header_nav a {
  font-family: arial;
  display: block;
  color:white!important;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14 px 16 px;
  text-decoration: none!important;
 }
```

Comment: I just changed it too the way you said. I have tried this before and this doesn't work as well.

Comment: This is really strange, if I run your code here on the website it works perfectly fine. But when I copy it to use in my project it doesn't work at all...

Comment: Check if you have any other styles that applied to `.header_nav` or `a` Order is mater for CSS as well.

Comment: The code I send, is the only code I am using right now. So no other styles applied to .header_nav or a

Comment: If there is something wrong with the order, why is it working in the snippet?  I really have no clue why it isn't working.

Comment: Is it changing with the latest update? Can you include a screenshot in your question?

Comment: I included a screenshot in my question.

Comment: Can you check in Chrome in dev panel is your CSS return 404?

Comment: Everything works fine now, Thank you very much for your time. (stupid mistake, was on the wrong html page when checking css)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are expecting, but it appears your class declarations are a little backwards.  It should be class then element so,

```
.header_nav li { your styles }
.header_nav a { your styles }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes:

From

```
a.header_nav { 

}
```

To:

```
.header_nav a {

}
```

and also you can make change to html for easiness

```css
body{
  background-color: #f1f6fe;
}

ul.header_nav_container {
    float:right;   
    padding: 20px;
}


ul.header_nav_container li.header_nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px
    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Xander Feliers - Portfolio</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Portfolio - Xander Feliers">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <nav>
            <ul class="header_nav_container">
                <li class="header_nav"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="header_nav"><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li class="header_nav"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="header_nav"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]
If class doesn't work you can specify ids and pass the styles similarly

Comment: Yeah, I first did it with ID's but thought it wasn't proper CSS too just fill it with ID's everywhere.

Comment: No, he wants to apply the style to multiple elements. `id` must be unique.